# Xcode7/ iOS 9 Enterprise Distribution not working with iPhone6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9

I am trying to distribute app for testing with Enterprise distribution/Ad-hoc distribution profiles and have valid distribution , provisioning profile and deployed on https server. My app works fine for some devices, even with iOS 9. But In few devices iPhone 6 I am getting error Unable to download error --'app cannot be download at this time'.

Is this issue with iOS 9 but This is happening with some devices only. download works fine in iPhone 5 but not with the iPhone 6. Do we have to make any change for iOS 9.

My Plist also has the same bundle-identifier to the app.

Comment: I've had problems depending on the network. For instance downloads would sometimes fail over our wifi, but work fine on 3G.

Comment: @JamesP not working on both wifi..mobile data..

Comment: what is xcode version used to make build?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried plugging the device into a Mac that is running Xcode and then looking at the device logs to see why the install is failing?  The logs can provide a great deal of information.